# Not sure if I understand how to create bit function

Tags: c, bit

How do I create some function that will turn on all the bits beginning at parameter 1's position and ending at parameter 2's position, assuming that the number of bits will always be less than 31 and greater than/0 to 0?

**My understanding:** I assume it wants me to return bits that are included from a and to b, and then turn off all the other bits. Would it involve some statement like:

```
(1 << a) and include all the bits all the way to (1 << b)?
```

I'm a bit confused about how to do this using only single statements?

Comment: You want a purely hypothetical algorithm, not specific for any language?

Comment: C is what I'm working with, but any algorithm would help here. Have just edited my understanding above as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a mask of `n` bits by:

```
mask = (1U << n) - 1;
```

So for your case,

```
int n = a - b + 1;
uint32_t mask = (1U << n) - 1;
uint32_t returnValue = mask << b;
```

This algorithm causes undefined bhaviour if `a` is `31` and `b` is `0` (`n` would be `32`, which is disallowed) - you might want to special case that if it can happen in your program.

Comment: Sorry, as I am new to this, what does "1U" refer to?

Comment: @marchon the `U` makes `1U` an `unsigned int` rather than the `signed int` you'd get from just a `1` constant.  I included it to avoid the undefined behaviour (sign change) that would occur if `n` were 31.

Comment: And if n were not 31, there would be no reason to include it. Is that right?

Comment: No reason not to, either.  `unsigned` values have better characteristics on the undefined-behaviour front in general.

Comment: Just so I understand, what does the " - 1" in the mask equation do?

Comment: Well, `1U << n` gives you a binary number that's a `1` followed by `n` zeroes.  Subtracting `1` from such a number yields a new binary number consisting of `n` `1` digits.

Comment: Example: Result of 1<<9 in binary: `... 0010 0000 0000`. Minus 1 is `... 0001 1111 1111`

Comment: In response to your edit, I can't special case it. We have to assume b can equal 0.

Comment: `b` can be `0`, as long as `a` isn't `31` at the same time.  If you really don't want a special case, just use larger types.

Comment: If we made the assumption that the rightmost bit is 0, I guess that would alleviate the special case, is that right?

Comment: Yes, it would be fine then.

Comment: Sorry - one last clarification, why would mask << b shift over the mask values by "b" amount without pushing over all the other 1s into the wrong position?

Comment: I think it pushes the other `1s` into the *right* position.  In the mask they're justified to the right side.